# Android get collection of current touches like in XNA

Tags: android, touch, xamarin.android

Is there any way to get a collection of current touches on screen or view, like in XNA for wp7? P.S. I am actually using monodroid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) :

> Motion events contain information about all of the pointers that are currently active even if some of them have not moved since the last event was delivered.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at monogame?  it provides XNA bindings for Android, https://github.com/mono/MonoGame